# отображение всех строк в блоке или с разными значениеми

Tags: c#

есть значит такая строка :

```
string stroka="aaaa";
```

если я буду дальше писать :

```
stroka="aaab";
stroka="aaab";
```

про цикл знаю, но не годится про вайл тоже не в кассу
вопрос такой: как добиться результата такого чтобы комп выдавал эти все строки 
я написал кодом так:

```
string stroka = "aaaa";
        stroka = "aaab";
        stroka = "aaac";
        stroka = "aaad";
        Console.WriteLine(stroka);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

железка естественно выдала мне только aaad, а мне надо получить все строки, не придавая им никакого другого значение, может через блок или как-то иначе, чтобы не писать так:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string stroka = "aaaa";
        string stroka1 = "aaab";
        string stroka2 = "aaac";
        string stroka3 = "aaad";
        Console.WriteLine(stroka);
        Console.WriteLine(stroka1);
        Console.WriteLine(stroka2);
        Console.WriteLine(stroka3);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

но мне это не годится!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Постановка вопроса ужасна, но я попробую.

```
string stroka = "aaaa";
Console.WriteLine(stroka);
stroka = "aaab";
Console.WriteLine(stroka);
stroka = "aaac";
Console.WriteLine(stroka);
stroka = "aaad";
Console.WriteLine(stroka);
```

**Upd.** «а если одной командой WriteLine(...)»:

```
Console.WriteLine("aaaa" + "\r\n" + "aaab" + "\r\n" + "aaac" + "\r\n" + "aaad");
```

Comment: а если одной командой WriteLine(...); 
"Постановка вопроса ужасна" - я достаточно нормально все обьяснил

Comment: @komra23, Добавил upd в ответ. Кстати, если Вы объясните исходную задачу, то ответ может быть намного содержательнее.

Comment: задача: 
мне надо получить все строки, не придавая им никакого другого значение, может через блок или как-то иначе, чтобы не писать так:

`static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string stroka = "aaaa";
        string stroka1 = "aaab";
        string stroka2 = "aaac";
        string stroka3 = "aaad";
        Console.WriteLine(stroka);
        Console.WriteLine(stroka1);
        Console.WriteLine(stroka2);
        Console.WriteLine(stroka3);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }`